# R function to replace values in a given range of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a likert scale ranging from 1 to 5, but in my survey database I made the mistake of labeling the answers as A1:A5.

```
`> dput(head(sample))
structure(list(ESIR_SQ001 = c(NA, "A4", 
"A4", "A3", "A3", NA), 
 ESIR_SQ002 = c(NA, "A2", "A4", "A3", "A4", 
 NA), ESIR_SQ003 = c(NA, 
 "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", NA), ESIR_SQ004 = 
 c(NA, "A1", "A2", 
 "A3", "A1", NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"
  ), row.names = c(NA, -6L))`
```

I have several scales and thousands of participants so I wonder if there is a way of replacing values on a range of variables of my data frame:

ex from col 1:5 (A1=1, A2=2, A3=3, A4=4, A5=5)

Answer (score 2):

We can coerce to `integer` after converting to `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom order. It would be a straightforward approach.
As the input dataset is a `tibble`, we can use `tidyverse` approaches.

```
library(dplyr)
Sample <- Sample %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~
      as.integer(factor(., levels = paste0("A", 1:5)))))
Sample
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  ESIR_SQ001 ESIR_SQ002 ESIR_SQ003 ESIR_SQ004
#       <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#1         NA         NA         NA         NA
#2          4          2          2          1
#3          4          4          2          2
#4          3          3          2          3
#5          3          4          2          1
#6         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

Or using `match` on the values in that order

```
Sample %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ match(., paste0("A", 1:5))))
```

---

Or another option is to remove the letter at the beginning

```
library(stringr)
Sample %>%
   mutate(across(everyting(), ~ as.integer(str_remove(., 'A'))))
```

Or with `parse_number`

```
Sample %>%
  mutate(across(everyting(), readr::parse_number))
```

---

Or if we want to use `base R`, it is easy as well

```
Sample[] <- lapply(Sample, function(x) 
      as.integer(factor(x, levels = paste0("A", 1:5))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually could do that very easily with `gsub`.

```
dat[1:4] <- lapply(dat[1:4], gsub, pattern="A", replacement="")
str(dat)
#   ESIR_SQ001 ESIR_SQ002 ESIR_SQ003 ESIR_SQ004
# 1       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
# 2          4          2          2          1
# 3          4          4          2          2
# 4          3          3          2          3
# 5          3          4          2          1
# 6       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

You could also pre-define a replacement function that simultaneously converts to numerics which you'll probably need.

```
gsub.num <- function(x) as.double(gsub("A", "", x))
dat[1:4] <- lapply(dat[1:4], gsub.num)
dat
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ ESIR_SQ001: num  NA 4 4 3 3 NA
#  $ ESIR_SQ002: num  NA 2 4 3 4 NA
#  $ ESIR_SQ003: num  NA 2 2 2 2 NA
#  $ ESIR_SQ004: num  NA 1 2 3 1 NA
```